# I was able to open a command prompt from my Java program, How to run some exe in this command prompt using java code?

Tags: java

I tried open a command prompt using java program, how to execute the some exe file in this command prompt using java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` or using ProcessBuilder.

Now, if you want to open command prompt on windows run pass "cmd.exe" to `exec()` method. You have to find which command to run for each other OS your application is targeted for.